# Replace B Git repo Master with another A Git repo master

Tags: git, github

I have 2 GIT repositories. Let's say A and B. Now I need to replace B master with A's master completely. I have done the same operation when B was empty. But now I have code on it. So how can I do that now?

I did this when B was empty.

`git remote set-url origin  https://github.com/sam/B.git`

`git push -u origin master`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have already configured your remote:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/sam/B.git
```

The following command should work:

```
git push -f origin master:master
```

it overwrites the remote master branch (`B`) with the "current" master branch (`A`)